# Understanding the adiabatic and sudden/diabatic approximations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations, adiabatic

I’m trying to build a stronger understanding of what the [adiabatic and sudden/diabatic approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem)  mean and imply through examples. Specifically, I want to know how energy is transferred based on these two examples. Any insights in my reasoning would be greatly appreciated, as (to be honest) I have no idea if what I'm thinking is correct. Below is my understanding of the approximations, but I have a feeling there are a lot of misconceptions that need to be pointed out!

I’m under the impression that the sudden approximation implies full energy transfer. The reason so is because if we have an initial state, $|\phi \rangle$ at time $t=0$, the sudden approximation tells us:

$$| \phi(t) \rangle = U(t, t_0)| \phi (0) \rangle  \approx |\phi (0) \rangle = |\phi \rangle$$

Since the Sudden Approximation assumes that time evolution is effectively the identity, or $U(t_0, t_0)$. Thus, in calculating the energy transfer after some time $t$, we look at the wave function overlaps:

$$ \langle \phi (t) | \phi(0) \rangle = \langle \phi (0) | \phi(0) \rangle = 1$$

I was using the toy example of a harmonic oscillator shifting:
$$ H(0) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m \omega^2 x^2 $$
$$ H(t_{later}) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m \omega^2 (x-x_0)^2 $$

For the adiabatic approximation, we aim to find a solution:

$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} | \Psi (t) \rangle = H(t) | \Psi (t) \rangle$$
Where we are working with a set of eigenstates

$$H(t)| \phi_n(t) \rangle = E_n(t) |\phi_n (t)\rangle $$

If we look back at our harmonic oscillator example, such that is takes a sufficiently long time to go from a displacement of 0 to $x_0$, and if we assume that we start in the ground state of the harmonic oscillator, the adiabatic approximation tells us that we can write our state as:

$$ | \Psi (t) \rangle = 1 e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}\int dt' E_{g.s.}(t')} | 0(t) \rangle$$

Where I define $ | 0(t) \rangle$ to be the state that starts in the normal harmonic oscillator ground state, but over some time $T$ becomes the coherent state $| 0(T) \rangle | x_0 \rangle$.

To find the energy transfer after $T$ I consider

$$\langle 0(T) |0(0) \rangle = \langle x_0 | 0\rangle $$

**So my main question:**
Is the way I'm calculating energy transferred correct? I thought of energy transfer to mean 'the amount of the state changes' but this feels completely wrong? The other idea I had was to calculate $$\langle \phi (t) | \hat{H} | \phi(0) \rangle $$ but this also feels strange because I wasn't sure which Hamiltonian I should use. For the sudden approximation, do I use $H$ at $t_0$, or at $t$ after. For the adiabatic approximation, do I use $H(t)$ or $H(t_0)$?

The reason this feels weird to me is intuitively I expected the adiabatic approximation to have 100% energy transfer since we change the state slowly. I then expect the sudden approximation to have no energy transfer since the Hamiltonian rapidly changes.

Comment: You are confusing the use of the term "adiabatic" which has different meanings in QM and thermodynamics. As the wikipedia article suggests by the *disambiguation* below the title.

Comment: I actually didn't link the cite so I'm unsure. But this link from MIT OCW defines what I'm used to calling the adiabatic approx?
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch6.pdf